# Haskell Stack `exec` executable not found despite path being searched

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Creating a fresh `haskell-stack` project fails to find the `project-exec` executable, despite searching the appropriate path. I'm not sure why. In particular,

`stack build` creates the `project-exec` inside `$PROJECT_DIR/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/.../bin/project-exe`

However, `stack exec project-exec` fails with:

> Executable named rse8-exec not found on path: ["$PROJECT_DIR/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.14/8.0.1/bin", ]

(to clarify, `$PROJECT_DIR` references and `...` are (hopefully) obvious placeholders for paths. the actual error contains the full path)

Comment: Does the file have executable permissions?

Comment: @jberryman yes it does. :(

Comment: Hmm I have seen this same issue just now too on a fresh ubuntu VM install.  `stack exec mytest` gives 
    Executable named mytest not found on path: [...] 
but `stack exec .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/mytest-exe/mytest-exe` runs the executable fine. Also I seemed to have no trouble with running 'stack exec simpletest' stack build of a project created with `stack new simpletest simple`. I am new to stack so not sure if I am doing something obviously wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apologies for the lack of attention showed here. This question should probably just be deleted.

Stack creates a file named `<project>-exe` *not* `<project>-exec`.

Answer (score 1):

`Stack` replaces dashes `-` with underscores `_`. Try `stack exec project_exec` see if it works.

This should have been a comment actually, but I don't have enough reputation to write a comment, while I have enough to post an answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. If I call `stack exec full/path/to/bin/project-exec` it works. This is a bit frustrating. It was working yesterday. I'm not sure what changed :/